# Regression for implicit polynomial functions of n-th order

Tags: statistics, regression

How to do regression using polynomials of the form $a_n x^n + a_{n-1} x^{n-1} y + \cdots+ a_0 y^n+ b_{n-1}x^{n-1}+b_{n-2}x^{n-2}y+\cdots=c$, given some data points $(x_i,y_i)$ (the number of data points is much greater than $2n+2$)?

The sources on the internet only seem to suggest the method for polynomial functions of the form $y=f(x)$.

Comment: The method of regression is the same as for any functions instead of polynomial of several variables (two variables $x,y$ in the present case). $$\sum_{k=1}^{k=p}a_kF_k(x,y)=-F_0(x,y)$$ where all functions $F_k$ are given functions, $-F_0(x,y)=c$ in the present case. $p+1$ is the total number of fonctions.. The unknown coefficients $a_k$ are computed thanks to linear regression. For example, see Sections 4 and 5 in :https://fr.scribd.com/doc/14819165/Regressions-coniques-quadriques-circulaire-spherique

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you have $p$ data points $(x_i,y_i)$ and that what is measured is $y$, in the least square sense, I do no thing that this is feasible.

One think you could do is to consider that you face a surabondant set of equations. So, just define $z_i=c \,\,\forall i$ and use multilinear regression or matrix calculations to get the $a$'s and $b$'s.

Answer (score 0):

Just do a linear regression like you normally would with any basis of functions: calculate the $x^ky^l$, put in the columns of a matrix $\bf \Phi$ in some order, then pose

$${\bf v_o}= \min_{\bf v}\|{\bf \Phi v}-c{\bf 1}\|_2^2$$

If you allow constant term ($k=l=0$), there will exist a trivial solution which you will need to dodge somehow.

For example by regularization on the coefficients of the polynomial.

The value at position $m$ in the vector $\bf v$ will be the coefficient for whichever of the $x^ky^l$ you stuffed as $m$th column in the $\bf \Phi$.